# Adding numerical values to -Infinity?

Tags: javascript

```
npc_objects = {};
TURKEYLENGTH =  (Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(npc_objects))) + 1;  
console.log(TURKEYLENGTH);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j40ucf6m/1/

As pertinent to my most recent question asked :P.. I just found out that `-Infinity` is actually a numerical value. I'm trying to add another numerical value to it, but it's still returning `-Infinity`. I have tried to move the +1 inside the parenthesis aswell. For example `(Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(npc_objects))+1);`

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: This is mathematically correct `-∞ + 1 = -∞`. Basically once you get to infinity you're stuck there.

Comment: Infinity is not a number. While you can represent infinity in floating point numbers (for example), they are almost entirely closed in being infinities - the only exception being operations like `Infinity * -42` being `-Infinity` and such. But even `Infinity - Infinity` results in just `NaN`. That's just (one) convenient way to work with infinities.

Comment: @Luaan That's what confused me. Infinity shows as a numerical value in console.log too and I thought I could modify it. Guess not >_< I am either over-thinking all this, or the dumbest person on this site lol.

Comment: It is a value you can represent in the "number type" in Javascript - but it still isn't a number. The usage in float numbers (and javascript) does actually make sense, but what you're trying to do doesn't make any - if you subtract one from infinity, the result is still infinity. If you subtract a billion from infinity, the result is still infinity. So why have infinity at all? It's a good ceiling or floor value for one; it can be used as a stopper. And of course, it makes some other operations easier - `1 / 0` is now simply `Infinity`, rather than producing an error. But `Infinity * 0 = NaN`.

Comment: `It is a value you can represent in the "number type" in Javascript - but it still isn't a number.` This just confuses the hell out of me ha, but I understand what it really means now. (In terms of javascript)  Hopefully. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you add `Infinity` to `-Infinity` you will always get the answer `-Infinity` (adding `Infinity` to it will give you `NaN`). If we were to know what `-Infinity + 1` is equal to, we'd then know what `-Infinity` is equal to (as a number), and this would make it a finite number and not an infinite number.

Comment: So, it's best to think of the `-Infinity` as just... infinity, not really a numerical value, because it cannot be changed, right? I just keep thinking since it's numeric it can be modified. I might be over-thinking this.

Comment: Actually, `Infinity + (-Infinity)` is `NaN`. Which is very reasonable, if you think about how infinity is not actually a number, and how you're likely to be using `Infinity` in Javascript (or other real number calculations). The same way, `Infinity * 0` is not zero, it's `NaN`. In math, it's simply an undefined operation.

Comment: @NiCkNewman the Mathematics Stack Exchange website can answer this one for us! [Is infinity a number?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yeah, I need to change my views of infinity and how it interacts with Javascript. Glad you helped.

Answer (score 2):

**Just as a side note**, and because we're speaking about javascript,

There is a value just before *`Infinity`*.

I have no resource about it, but it seems that the largest value before `Infinity` is `-179769313486231580793728971405303415079934132710037826936173778980444968292764750946649017977587207096330286416692887910946555547851940402630657488671505820681908902000708383676273854845817711531764475730270069855571366959622842914819860834936475292719074168444365510704342711559699508093042880177904174497791.99999 //+ infinity of 9`.

And you can take the same number `*-1` to find the cliff before `-∞`

There is also a cliff before a float number becomes an int, look at the snippet.

```js
var cliffBeforeInfinity = 179769313486231580793728971405303415079934132710037826936173778980444968292764750946649017977587207096330286416692887910946555547851940402630657488671505820681908902000708383676273854845817711531764475730270069855571366959622842914819860834936475292719074168444365510704342711559699508093042880177904174497791.99999; //+ infinity of 9

var realInfinity= 179769313486231580793728971405303415079934132710037826936173778980444968292764750946649017977587207096330286416692887910946555547851940402630657488671505820681908902000708383676273854845817711531764475730270069855571366959622842914819860834936475292719074168444365510704342711559699508093042880177904174497792;

var almost_zero = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024703282292062327208828439643411068618252990130716238221279284125033775363510437593264991818081799618989828234772285886546332835517796989819938739800539093906315035659515570226392290858392449105184435931802849936536152500319370457678249219365623669863658480757001585769269903706311928279558551332927834338409351978015531246597263579574622766465272827220056374006485499977096599470454020828166226237857393450736339007967761930577506740176324673600968951340535537458516661134223766678604162159680461914467291840300530057530849048765391711386591646239524912623653881879636239373280423891018672348497668235089863388587925628302755995657524455507255189313690836254779186948667994968324049705821028513185451396213837722826145437693412532098591327667236328125001;

var zero = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000247032822920623272088284396434110686182529901307162382212792841250337753635104375932649918180817996189898282347722858865463328355177969898199387398005390939063150356595155702263922908583924491051844359318028499365361525003193704576782492193656236698636584807570015857692699037063119282795585513329278343384093519780155312465972635795746227664652728272200563740064854999770965994704540208281662262378573934507363390079677619305775067401763246736009689513405355374585166611342237666786041621596804619144672918403005300575308490487653917113865916462395249126236538818796362393732804238910186723484976682350898633885879256283027559956575244555072551893136908362547791869486679949683240497058210285131854513962138377228261454376934125320985913276672363281245;

var p = document.querySelector('p');
p.innerHTML+='cliff Before Infinity : '+cliffBeforeInfinity;
p.innerHTML+='<br>';
p.innerHTML+='Infinity : '+ realInfinity;
p.innerHTML+='<br>';
p.innerHTML+='cliff before -Infinity : '+cliffBeforeInfinity*-1;
p.innerHTML+='<br>';
p.innerHTML+='-Infinity : '+realInfinity*-1;
p.innerHTML+='<br>';
p.innerHTML+='almost zero : '+almost_zero;
p.innerHTML+='<br>';
p.innerHTML+='zero : '+ zero;
```

```html
<p></p>
```